# Error en c++ orientado a objetos: no match for 'operator='

Tags: c++

Intenté crear un vector llamado `pelotas` de tipo `Pelota` pero me da este error:

> error: no match for 'operator=' in
> '((Inventario*)this)->Inventario::pelotas[5] = (operator new(60u), (, ((Pelota*))))' (operand types are 'Pelota' and 'Pelota*')

```
#include "Inventario.h"


Inventario::Inventario() {

}
Inventario::Inventario(int tam, int iniFinal){
    this->tamanio=tam;
    this->indiceFinal=iniFinal;
    this->pelotas[5]=new Pelota();
}
```

Comment: intenta quitando el `new`

Comment: Con `this->pelotas[5]` haces referencia al elemento en la posición 5 si es un arreglo. Deberías dar más información, como la estructura y qué intentas hacer.

Answer (score 0):

```
this->pelotas[5]=new Pelota();
```

Esta línea está mal.

Entendiendo que la declaración debería ser así:

```
class Inventario
{
    Pelota * pelotas;
};
```

Ya que de otra forma no podrías usar el operador `new`, la inicialización de esta variable sería:

```
Inventario::Inventario(int tam, int iniFinal)
{
    this->pelotas = new Pelota[5];
}
```